# Pipenv: Activate virtual environment on new computer after git clone

Tags: python, django, git-clone, pipenv

I copied a repo containing a Python Django project from my old computer to my new one via `git clone`. I manage my dependecies in the project via pipenv.

After successfully cloning my repo I wanted to start working on the new computer and tried to select the relevant python interpreter for my project in VS Code . However, the path was not on the list.

So first I tried the command `pipenv --venv` which gave me the feedback: `No virtualenv has been created for this project`

So I thought I might need to activate the virtual environment first, before being able to select it in VS Studio code. So i ran `pipenv shell` in the root directory of my project.

However this seem to have created a new virtual environment: `Creating a virtualenv for this project… Pipfile: C:\path\to\my\cloned\project\Pipfile`

My questions:
1.) Is this the correct way to activate a pipenv virtualenvironment on a new computer after copying the project via git clone? And if not,...
2.1) Does the way I did it cause any problems, which I should be aware of?
2.2) What would be the correct procedure to activate my virtual enviroment on a new computer?

Answer (score 1):

In general an environment image probably shouldn't be copied to github. You'll get a bunch of unneeded files which clogs your repo.

Instead you should create a `requirements.txt` from your existing environment `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and commit that file.

Then when someone else clones your repo they can set up a new virtual environment using any tool they want and run `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt`

That is, `requirements.txt` is like a recipe for how to create your environment. By providing the recipe users can use it any way they want.

Answer (score -1):

use:

```sh
pipenv install
```

It worked on Ubuntu, should work also on a mac.
I tried on a windows, it triggered some errors.

"If you download a source repository for a project that uses Pipenv for package management, all you need to do is unpack the contents of the repository into a directory and run pipenv install (no package names needed). Pipenv will read the Pipfile and Pipfile.lock files for the project, create the virtual environment, and install all of the dependencies as needed."
https://www.infoworld.com/article/3561758/how-to-manage-python-projects-with-pipenv.html